# How to read .csv file using BlobId

Tags: scala, google-cloud-storage

Below is my code that returning NullPointer exception. but reading using fileReader it is returning value as expected.

```
var readChannel:ReadChannel  = storage.reader(blobId)
var excelFileRead:InputStream =  Channels.newInputStream(readChannel)
var br:BufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(excelFileRead))
var csvReader: CSVReader = new CSVReader(br)
csvReader.readNext
```

Comment: Please provide proper Java code, and also the complete stacktrace for the exception.  (With the question in its current form, the best we can do is to close it as a dup of the *canonical* question on fixing NPEs.)

Comment: added the code please provide the solutions

Comment: I don't see the stacktrace .....

Comment: Please find the stacke trace

Comment: 2021-02-15 11:42:35.958+0530 XAV-602000112 67128 [http-nio-8084-exec-1] ERROR 
 o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/galileo/api/v1] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef$.length$extension(ArrayOps.scala:192)
 at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.length(ArrayOps.scala:192)
 at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:32)

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Please, check this on [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Can you provide a self contained code that can be used to reproduce your issue? where are you running this code (app engine, cloud run)? make sure that you post the new information in your question and not in the comment as this will help the community to understand your issue better and they can refer to your question whenever someone else has the same issue in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the kind suggestion @MethkalKhalawi.  i fixed the issue and now it is working fine for me.

Comment: hi @avinashkumartiwari , can you please post your solution for community reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please find the beow code that is working fine for me:-**Initially i was using CsvReader that was returning the null value but it is working fine with BufferReader as shown below.

```
  def getHeaderFromFile(blobId: BlobId,storage: Storage): Array[String] = {
   val readChannel:ReadChannel  = storage.reader(blobId)
   val excelFileRead:InputStream =  Channels.newInputStream(readChannel)
   val br:BufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(excelFileRead))
   val header:String = br.readLine()
   val headers: Array[String] = header.split(",")
    headers
  }
```